What sorts of operators satisfy this condition?
I'm trying to find some operators $P:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfy these properties (it is okay to assume $\mathbb{X} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact):
(i) $\|\sum_{k=1}^N p_{i} P(x_i) - x \|_2^2 \le \|\sum_{k=1}^N p_{i} x_i - x \|_2^2$, where $x\in \mathbb{X}$, $x_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$, for $\sum_{k=1}^N p_{i}=1$, $p_{i}\ge0$.
(ii) For all $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\|P(y)\|<B$ for some $B>0$.
I'm trying to find an operator $P$ that does not depend on $x$ (as otherwise I can set $P(y)=x$ for $y \in \mathbb{X}$). Here, $x$ is a given point in $\mathbb{X}$. Would anybody have any ideas on how to do this? I've been struggling with this for quite a while and am wondering how to proceed. I've tried the projection operator and setting $\mathbb{X}$ to be a large ball, but no luck. I'm guessing a projection operator with $\mathbb{X}$ chosen to be a clever, convex-like set will work but have made no progress.

What’s the problem with just $P(y) = y$?

@DavidGao Sorry, there was a mistype: The operator should remain bounded over all $\mathbb{R}^n$

I’m a bit confused. Isn’t $P$ only defined on $X$? Did you intend for it to be defined on the entirety of $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead? But then what is the purpose of $X$?

Also, when you write $\sum_i p_i = 1$, are $p_i$ arbitrary real numbers? Or do they have to be nonnegative?

Also, when you say $P$ does not depend on $x$, what does $x$ refer to?

(Though, at this point it’s safe to say under reasonable interpretation of what you meant, no such $P$ can exist unless $X$ is just a single point. But I’ll wait for the clarifications to my questions above to make sure I’m not misunderstanding the question.)

@DavidGao, yes, that is all correct. I should have written these from the start (it was late at night when I posted this question). $p_i$ are non-negative, though I'd be interested to know if such $P$ exists if $p_i$ can just be real numbers. $x$ is just a fixed point, and I'm trying to find a $P$ given such (fixed, single) $x$.

You didn't exactly address this in your edit: Is $P$ defined on $\mathbb{X}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$? Because in the former case, your condition $2$ makes no sense.

@DavidGao Thanks for pointing this out! Gosh, I left so many typos. Originally, $P: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{X}$, but I'd be very interested to know about the more general $P:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ case as well.

Now that all the typos have been cleared up - no, no such $P$ exists, unless $\mathbb{X}$ is a singleton (in which case, if $\mathbb{X} = \{x\}$, then of course $P(y) = x$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ works). Indeed, assume to the contrary that $\mathbb{X}$ has at least two points and such a $P$ exists. Then we must have $P(x) = x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{X}$. Indeed, by condition (i), whenever $x \in \mathbb{X}$,
$$\|P(x) - x\| \leq \|x - x\| = 0$$
So $P(x) = x$. Now, as $\mathbb{X}$ has at least two points, we may choose $x, y \in \mathbb{X}$ with $x \neq y$. Thus, there exists a point $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ on the ray starting at $y$ and pointing in the direction $y - x$ s.t. $\|z\| \geq B$. So, by condition (ii), $P(z) \neq z$. Note that $y$ is on the line segment connecting $x$ and $z$, so there exists $p, q \geq 0$, $p + q = 1$, s.t. $y = px + qz$. Thus, by condition (i),
$$\|px + qP(z) - y\| = \|pP(x) + qP(z) - y\| \leq \|px + qz - y\| = 0$$
So $px + qP(z) = y = px + qz$. Note that $q \neq 0$, as otherwise $p = 1$ and $y = x$, contradicting the assumption that $x \neq y$. Thus,
$$P(z) = \frac{1}{q}(px + qz - px) = z$$
which is a contradiction.
